# user-by-username-query needing more than 1 parameter

Tags: java, security, spring, spring-security

I have to implement a spring security piece which has more than 1 parameter for getting users.  It will get a user by its ID and a product name. I know that the user-by-username-query can only give the one parameter, I was wondering if it's possible to give many users-by-username-query options and give them some sort of ID, but I'm not sure how that would be referenced when authenticating.  Does anyone have any suggestions

```
<sec:authentication-provider>

<sec:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
    users-by-username-query="
    select username,password,enabled 
    from MY_USERS where username=? and product='productA'" />
```

Comment: It is likely you will need to write your own user service and possibly more than that.

Comment: I have same problem. I have several applications referring common userbase & I want to pass query them based on extra parameter as 'ApplicationId'. Can you please tell me how you have achieved it. Thanking You !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to implement your own [AuthenticationProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html)

*You can not reuse the [DaoAuthenticationProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html) (jdbc-user-service), because it uses a 
[UserDetailsService](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html), and this has a method to load the UserDetails based on only one string argument `UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)`*

Comment: How to implement out custom Authentication provider ? Any sample.Or I can simply extend DaoAuthenticationProvider & create custom one

Comment: http://jpgmr.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/implementing-your-own-userdetailsservice-is-easy-with-spring-roo-and-spring-data-jpa/ or use google