# Spring Security users-by-username-query with id_user

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to use spring security but I've never used it before.I want to retrieve user and roles from my tables (users,roles and user_roles).I have investigated about **users-by-username-query**. In all examples were same as the following example.

```
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
      users-by-username-query=
        "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
      authorities-by-username-query=
        "select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

But I want to use  **id_user** and **id_role** instead of  **username** and **role**. Is it possible ? And must I change login page field names ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: here is a good discussion about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069019/user-by-username-query-needing-more-than-1-parameter

Comment: Why you don't retrieve your fields `id_user` and `id_role` and just aply an alias to them in the same query? It is probably the simplest way of achieving that. I´ve done it several times: `users-by-username-query="  select user.user_login as username, user.user_pwd as password, user.user_enabled as enabled from user where user.user_login=?"`

Comment: Ok if it is possible to use like you said I'll try it.Thank you for your response.

Comment: But my  user_role table doesnt have column which stands by role name

Comment: How I can declare my authorities-by-username-query  ?

Comment: My user_role table contains three  columns ( id_user_role, id_user, id_role)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a common situation.

First, as I suggested in comments, use aliases to rename the fields which represent username, password and wether the user is enabled or not. Just like this:

```
users-by-username-query=
  "select user.user_login as username, user.user_pwd as password, user.user_enabled as enabled 
  from user where user.user_login=?"
```

Then, is usual too to have the `authorities` in a different table somehow related with the `user` table. This is a common case:

[image]

Where users are related with roles in a `n-to-n` relationship.

In this case, the `authorities-by-username-query` should be like this

```
 authorities-by-username-query=
        "SELECT users.name as username, roles.role as role 
        FROM users 
        INNER JOIN user_role ON users.id_user = user_role.id_user 
        INNER JOIN roles ON user_role.id_role = roles.id_role
        WHERE users.name = ?  "
```

As a test, for a set of tables containing this data:

users:

[image: users table content]

roles:

[image: roles table content]

user_role

[image: user-role table content]

for a received username *jlumietu* the result should be this:

[image: authorities-by-username-query result]

Finally, I've had some cases where I have extended [org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html) but I think that this is the simplest way of doing this kind of handling

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it still didn't work for me. I only got Error 401 unauthorized request. Basically, the whole authentication didn't go through.

Comment: @ChandaraChea This is a well tested solution, which I've running in so many applications. If "the whole authentication didn't go throught" as you said, I think you should check the filter mappings. If you want to, you could write and answer and post a link here to it, I will check it as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

For string boot 2 It's worked this way

```
package com.gkatzioura.spring.security.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

import javax.sql.DataSource;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class PasswordEncodedSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                //.passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,enabled from users where username =?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(" select u.username, r.name from users u join user_role ur on u.id = ur.user_id " +
                        " join role r on ur.role_id = r.id where u.username =?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/public").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().permitAll()
                .and().logout() .permitAll();
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return passwordEncoder;
    }
    

}
```

Comment: What is preventing SQL injection in your custom queries?